# How to share global variables between Lua scripts

Tags: lua

I would like to know how to share global variables between Lua scripts.

I tried to do this myself using `require` but it doesn't work as I expected.

Here's my simple example code.

In `test.lua`

```
num = 2
```

In `A.lua`

```
require(`test`);
num = 5
```

In `B.lua`

```
require(`test`);
print(num);
```

And if I run `A.lua` first, then `B.lua`, I get the following result:

```
2
```

But I expect to get `5` because I modified the variable value to `2` in `A.lua`.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? (I would appreciate an example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are currently doing is the following:

```
lua A.lua
> lua process starts
> loading A.lua
> loading test.lua (because it is required by A.lua)
> set global "num" to value 2
> set global "num" to value 5
> lua process exits (A.lua finished)
lua B.lua
> lua process starts
> loading B.lua
> loading test.lua (because it is required by B.lua)
> set global "num" to value 2
> print global "num" (which was set to 2 by test.lua)
> lua process exits (B.lua finished)
```

To print the value 5 your scripts should look like this:

```
-- test.lua
num = 2

-- A.lua
require("test")
num = 5

-- B.lua
require("test")
require("A")
print(num)
```

which will result in:

```
lua B.lua
> lua process starts
> loading B.lua
> loading test.lua (because it is required by B.lua)
> set global "num" to value 2
> loading A.lua (because it is required by B.lua)
> skip loading test.lua (has already been loaded)
> set global "num" to value 5
> print global "num"
> lua process exits (B.lua finished)
```

EDIT:
I see you're using the C Api of Lua and not a Lua binary to execute your scripts. Using the programming api you should be able the get your required result by executing A.lua and B.lua using the same lua-state (most commonly stored in the C-Variable "L").

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Now I understand how it works. Could you please show me an example of `Using the programming api you should be able the get your required result by executing A.lua and B.lua using the same lua-state`?

Comment: I never worked with the programming api myself, but what afaik as long as you pass the same `lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();` the both script executions, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

a.lua

```
a = 5
```

b.lua

```
require('a')
a = 2
```

test.lua

```
require('b')
print(a)
```

You should get 2, because the require chain works from top-bottom, if you just run each file a time lua will execute just this little uniq execution, there is no persistency acros diferent executions, so you need to require as needed

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated function to require Lua modules from the C-API.<sup>[1]</sup>  So I oriented myself on the function [`dolibrary`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.c.html#dolibrary) in the Lua interpreter to implement `require` which simply calls the Lua `require` function from C.

*N.B.:*  I don't recommend having modules communicate by sharing global variables, especially when the order of loading the modules matters as is the case here.  Better provide methods `A.update_num(old)` and `B.update_num(old)` which take the old value of `num` as an argument and return the updated value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <lua.hpp>

int require(lua_State *L, char const * modname) {
    int const size = lua_gettop(L);

    lua_getglobal(L, "require");
    lua_pushstring(L, modname);

    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, 1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L,1);
        return 0; // Failed, nothing should be on the stack
    }

    return lua_gettop(L) - size;
}

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    require(L, "A");
    require(L, "B");

    lua_close(L);
}
```

With the scripts from your question in the same directory we get:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2/ test.cpp -llua5.2
$ ./a.out 
5
```

---

[1] There is [`lua_requiref`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_requiref) to require Lua C modules from the C-API.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Although it is very useful to know, I think it doesn't really answer the problem I want to solve. I would appreciate if you could take a look at my other question which I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335428/sharing-global-variables-between-different-lua-states-through-require