# Sharing global variables between different Lua states through require

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to find a way to share global variables of a specific Lua script(`test.lua` in the example) between different Lua states.

Here's my simple example code:

In `test.lua`

```
num = 2
```

In `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lua.hpp>
int main() 
{    
    lua_State *L1 = luaL_newstate(); //script A
    luaL_openlibs(L1);
    lua_settop(L1, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L1, "require('test') num = 5");

    lua_State *L2 = luaL_newstate(); //script B
    luaL_openlibs(L2);
    lua_settop(L2, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L2, "require('test') print(num)");

    lua_close(L1);
    lua_close(L2);
}
```

I expect to get `5` but I get `2`.

Is not possible to share global variables between different `lua_State*` through `require`?

**ADDED :**

If it's not possible, would it be a good idea to open `test.lua` using `luaL_loadfile` and then create getter/setter methods in C++ to share variable `num` between script `A` and `B`?

For example like this,

Script A:

```
script = my.Script("test")
script:setVar("num", 5)
```

Script B:

```
script = my.Script("test")
print(script:getVar("num"))
```

I wonder what you think about this design as an alternative to `require`.

Comment: It is not possible with a number, but if `num` was C userdata, the two VMs could access the same memory.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your comment. I would appreciate if you could show me an example of accessing the same memory between two `lua_State*` using the `userdata`.

Comment: You can use my answer to another question of yours as a starting point (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50600153).  I see that you really want other people to write code for you but writing all these metatables and metamethods and testing them is a lot of work.  I'd maybe do it for money but even then I probably have better things to do.

Comment: And you should purchase a copy of [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/).  All the techniques that I mentioned here are described in detail with examples, so you can copy, paste and adapt.

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm sorry for asking questions without enough self-research. I understand your point. I will be careful next time. And thank you for your book suggestion.

Comment: Your questions are well-researched but you always ask for answers which spoon-feed you the solution in the form of a copyable example.  Instead you should try stuff yourself and come back when you get stuck.  That said, please keep asking questions, I like them.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an even more complex version.  Maybe you want to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having the global value in a Lua module, you could push a pointer to a C++ value as an upvalue for a metatable to a table which contains those globals.  Then you push the `globals` table with the same metatable to both VMs.  When you now access `globals.num` the `getglobal` and `setglobal` metamethods are triggered (depending on whether you read or write).  These will update the value on the C++ side, such that it is shared between the two VMs.

*N.B.:* As you can judge from the lengthy boilerplate this is not a good solution.  You should avoid having multiple VMs at the same time.  If you require multiple VMs for concurrency purposes, consider using a mature library like [Lua Lanes](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes) rather than rolling your own (doing this right requires several thousands of lines of code).

```
#include <string>

#include <lua.hpp>

int setglobal(lua_State *L) {
    void *p = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "globals_meta");
    luaL_argcheck(L, p != nullptr, 1, "invalid userdata");

    std::string key = lua_tostring(L, 2);
    luaL_argcheck(L, key == "num", 2, "unknown global");

    int value = luaL_checkinteger(L, 3);
    luaL_argcheck(L, lua_isnumber(L, 3), 3, "not a number");

    int *num = static_cast<int *>(lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
    *num = value;
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    return 0;
}

int getglobal(lua_State *L) {
    void *p = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "globals_meta");
    luaL_argcheck(L, p != nullptr, 1, "invalid userdata");

    std::string key = lua_tostring(L, 2);
    luaL_argcheck(L, key == "num", 2, "unknown global");

    int num = *static_cast<int *>(lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    lua_pushinteger(L, num);
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg globals_meta[] = {
    {"__newindex", setglobal},
    {"__index", getglobal},
    {nullptr, nullptr} // sentinel
};

int main() {
    int num = 2;

    // script A

    lua_State *L1 = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L1);

    luaL_newmetatable(L1, "globals_meta");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L1, &num);
    luaL_setfuncs(L1, globals_meta, 1);

    lua_newuserdata(L1, 0);
    luaL_getmetatable(L1, "globals_meta");
    lua_setmetatable(L1, -2);
    lua_setglobal(L1, "globals");

    luaL_dostring(L1, "print('Script A: ' .. globals.num) globals.num = 5");

    // script B

    lua_State *L2 = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L2);

    luaL_newmetatable(L2, "globals_meta");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L2, &num);
    luaL_setfuncs(L2, globals_meta, 1);

    lua_newuserdata(L2, 0);
    luaL_getmetatable(L2, "globals_meta");
    lua_setmetatable(L2, -2);
    lua_setglobal(L2, "globals");

    luaL_dostring(L2, "print('Script B: ' .. globals.num)");

    lua_close(L1);
    lua_close(L2);
}
```

---

As a challange to myself I implemented a complete global table which can communicate values of type `nil`, `bool`, `int`, `double`, and `string` between two Lua states.  They can be named with everything that has a string representation.

```lua
-- To be on the safe side, just use numbers and strings as keys
globals[1] = "x"
globals.num = 5

-- Be careful when using table or function literals as keys
-- Two empty tables don't have the same representation
globals[{}] = 2 -- "table: 0x10d55a0" = 2
globals[{}] = 1 -- "table: 0x10ce2c0" = 1
```

I haven't checked all sorts of exceptional situations exhaustively, so no refunds!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <lua.hpp>

enum class nil {};
using Variant = boost::variant<nil, bool, int, double, std::string>;

int setglobal(lua_State *L) {
    void *p = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "globals_meta");
    luaL_argcheck(L, p != nullptr, 1, "invalid userdata");

    std::string key = luaL_tolstring(L, 2, nullptr);

    auto &globals = *static_cast<std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant> *>(
        lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
    Variant &v = globals[key];

    switch (lua_type(L, 3)) {
    case LUA_TNIL:
        v = nil{};
        break;
    case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
        v = static_cast<bool>(lua_toboolean(L, 3));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        break;
    case LUA_TNUMBER:
        if (lua_isinteger(L, 3)) {
            v = static_cast<int>(luaL_checkinteger(L, 3));
        } else {
            v = static_cast<double>(luaL_checknumber(L, 3));
        }
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        break;
    case LUA_TSTRING:
        v = std::string(lua_tostring(L, 3));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        break;
    default:
        std::string error = "Unsupported global type: ";
        error.append(lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, 3)));
        lua_pushstring(L, error.c_str());
        lua_error(L);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getglobal(lua_State *L) {
    void *p = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "globals_meta");
    luaL_argcheck(L, p != nullptr, 1, "invalid userdata");

    std::string key = luaL_tolstring(L, 2, nullptr);

    auto globals = *static_cast<std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant> *>(
        lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    auto search = globals.find(key);
    if (search == globals.end()) {
        lua_pushstring(L, ("unknown global: " + key).c_str());
        lua_error(L);
        return 0;
    }
    Variant const &v = search->second;

    switch (v.which()) {
    case 0:
        lua_pushnil(L);
        break;
    case 1:
        lua_pushboolean(L, boost::get<bool>(v));
        break;
    case 2:
        lua_pushinteger(L, boost::get<int>(v));
        break;
    case 3:
        lua_pushnumber(L, boost::get<double>(v));
        break;
    case 4:
        lua_pushstring(L, boost::get<std::string>(v).c_str());
        break;
    default: // Can't happen
        std::abort();
        break;
    }

    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg globals_meta[] = {
    {"__newindex", setglobal},
    {"__index", getglobal},
    {nullptr, nullptr} // sentinel
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant> globals;
    globals["num"] = 2;

    // script A

    lua_State *L1 = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L1);

    luaL_newmetatable(L1, "globals_meta");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L1, &globals);
    luaL_setfuncs(L1, globals_meta, 1);

    lua_newuserdata(L1, 0);
    luaL_getmetatable(L1, "globals_meta");
    lua_setmetatable(L1, -2);
    lua_setglobal(L1, "globals");

    if (luaL_dostring(L1, "print('Script A: ' .. globals.num)\n"
                          "globals.num = 5") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "L1:" << lua_tostring(L1, -1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L1, 1);
    }

    // script B

    lua_State *L2 = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L2);

    luaL_newmetatable(L2, "globals_meta");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L2, &globals);
    luaL_setfuncs(L2, globals_meta, 1);

    lua_newuserdata(L2, 0);
    luaL_getmetatable(L2, "globals_meta");
    lua_setmetatable(L2, -2);
    lua_setglobal(L2, "globals");

    if (luaL_dostring(L2, "print('Script B: ' .. globals.num)") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "L1:" << lua_tostring(L2, -1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L2, 1);
    }

    lua_close(L1);
    lua_close(L2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your long detailed answer. Now I understand what you meant by `if num was C userdata, the two VMs could access the same memory` but I actually need the two VMs to share the variable of the third script which in my example is `test.lua`. And I think it's not possible using `require` so I think I will create `getter` and `setter` functions. Anyways, your example has helped me understand how to make use of `userdata` in Lua so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Two distinct `lua_State`s are completely and totally independent. One cannot directly affect anything that happens in another. You can expose some C code to one that allows it to modify the other, or they could both access some external resource (a file, for example) that allows them to share data.

But outside of things like this, no, they cannot interact.

The preferred method for this is to not make them separate `lua_State`s.

Answer (score 1):

While Lua states are separate by default, some binding libraries expose functionality to transfer information from one to the other.

For example, in [sol](https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threading.html), there are methods to serialize fairly arbitrary Lua data, including functions, to C++ data. You can then de-serialize that data into another Lua state, to effectively copy it ([code link](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2/blob/d9c034d67263671bc35d3e3a3acc29682ebab88d/examples/source/docs/std_thread.cpp#L85)).

But you still will have two copies, in the end. You can't modify one Lua state from another directly.

Your last point, about exposing some getter/setter, is valid. You can have some data stored in C/C++ and have two different Lua states able to access it. You still have to bind that data to each VM separately.