# How to set global C++ pointer for lua_State

Tags: c++, lua

How to set global c++ pointer for lua_State once. And get it from C function.

```
Context *context = new Context();
lua_State *lua = luaL_newstate();

// Store context in lua state

lua_pushcfunction(lua, fn_one);
lua_setglobal(lua, "one");
// Register other global functions
```

I will get it from all my functions

```
int fn_one(lua_State *lua) 
{
   Context *context = (Context *) lua_touserdata(lua, -1);
   // context is null or error get object
   return 0;
}
```

I can set once and get in all my global functions.

This is for pass C++ pointer in Lua context

Comment: I will use lua_State in different files. I can store some C++ pointer in lua_State and get it from function. Static variable not solution.

Comment: Consider using extern if your code exists in several source files: `extern lua_State* L = nullptr;`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to just push the pointer as light userdata into the same module.  That way you can easily access the resource from every Lua function by simply passing it as an argument.

You could also use an upvalue, which is implicitly available inside a C closure without having to pass it as an argument.  I have already answered this elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337524

```cpp
#include <lua.hpp>

struct Context {
    int i;
};

int fn_one(lua_State *L)  {
    luaL_checkany(L, 1);
    Context *context = static_cast<Context *>(lua_touserdata(L, 1));
    lua_pushinteger(L, context->i);
    return 1;
}

extern "C" int luaopen_example (lua_State *L) {
    Context *context = new Context{42};
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, fn_one);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "one");
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, context);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "ctx");
    return 1;
}
```

```lua
local ex = require("example")
print(ex.ctx)
print(ex.one(ex.ctx))
```

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.3/ -shared -fPIC -o example.so example.cpp
$ lua5.3 test.lua
userdata: 0x55a81d6af920
42
```

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iRJwSZ513HEaNx7R)